# Create checkstyle.xml from IDEA codeStyleSettings.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting, checkstyle

I'm using gradle [checkstyle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html) plugin for my project. I already have code style setting in IDEA in `codeStyleSettings.xml` file. I want to generate `checkstyle.xml` config file from me IDEA code style settings. Can I do this?

Comment: Pretty sure that's not possible. You may want to [request it](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues) as a new feature.